# Tab function no longer working on r code, it is all appearing on every page

Tags: r, tabs, shinydashboard

I am currently developing a shiny dashboard, the code was working well fro having different things on each tab page however the code now seems to have stopped working and is putting several tabs all on one page and this is the same for every tab.

I have tried changing checking and changing brackets around however i cant seem to find the source of the problem

### Sidebar content

```
dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Home",tabName = "Home",icon=icon("home",lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("Training", tabName = "Training", icon=icon("bicycle",lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("Attitudes to Training", tabName ="Attitudes to Training",icon=icon("book",lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("Recovery",tabName="Recovery",icon=icon("battery-half",lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("Sleep" , tabName = "Sleep", icon=icon("bed",lib="font-awesome")),
            menuItem("Mood", tabName = "Mood", icon=icon("meh",lib="font-awesome"))           
        )),
```

### Body Content

```
dashboardBody(
tabItems(
#first item content
tabItem(tabName="Home",
           fluidRow(
            box(title = "Hi this is the home page", "Thankyou for taking part in our study, please login in at the top of the page using the log in details we have given you over email 
                to view your data. By navigating threough the side panel you will be able to view all of you daily data which you filled out, You can also view your fitness data under 
                the fitness tab and personality data under the personality tab.",solidHeader=TRUE, imageOutput( "Logo", height="auto"))
            
  ),
  
#second item content
tabItem(tabName="Training",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Weekly Training Hours", solidHeader = TRUE,background= "aqua",width = 12, height = NULL),
          "Training Hours",plotOutput(outputId = "Training"))
), 

tabItem(tabName = "Attitudes to Training",
            fluidRow(
          box(title = "Daily Scores for Atitudes to Training", solidHeader = TRUE,background= "aqua",width = 12, height = NULL),
          "Attitudes to Training",plotOutput(outputId = "Attitudes to Training"))
          ),

#forth item content
tabItem(tabName="Recovery",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Hi this is the Recovery page"))
), 
#fifth item content
tabItem(tabName = "Sleep",
            fluidRow(
              box(title= "Daily Scores for Sleep", solidHeader = TRUE,background = "blue", width=12,height = NULL),
              "Sleep",plotOutput(outputId = "Sleep"))
    ),
    
#sixth item conent
tabItem(tabName="Mood",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Hi this is the mood page"))
)

)
```

)
)
)

I want to get it so that each tab displays a different thing working again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already suspected, you made a mistake with the brackets. You did not close the bracket of the first tabItem. So you need to add a bracket after the one closing the fluidRow function and delete one at the end of your code:

```
dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
                #first item content
                tabItem(tabName="Home",
                        fluidRow(
                            box(title = "Hi this is the home page", "Thankyou for taking part in our study, please login in at the top of the page using the log in details we have given you over email 
                    to view your data. By navigating threough the side panel you will be able to view all of you daily data which you filled out, You can also view your fitness data under 
                    the fitness tab and personality data under the personality tab.",solidHeader=TRUE, imageOutput( "Logo", height="auto"))

                        )),

                #second item content
                tabItem(tabName="Training",
                        fluidRow(
                            box(title = "Weekly Training Hours", solidHeader = TRUE,background= "aqua",width = 12, height = NULL),
                            "Training Hours",plotOutput(outputId = "Training"))
                ), 

                tabItem(tabName = "Attitudes to Training",
                        fluidRow(
                            box(title = "Daily Scores for Atitudes to Training", solidHeader = TRUE,background= "aqua",width = 12, height = NULL),
                            "Attitudes to Training",plotOutput(outputId = "Attitudes to Training"))
                ),

                #forth item content
                tabItem(tabName="Recovery",
                        fluidRow(
                            box(title = "Hi this is the Recovery page"))
                ), 
                #fifth item content
                tabItem(tabName = "Sleep",
                        fluidRow(
                            box(title= "Daily Scores for Sleep", solidHeader = TRUE,background = "blue", width=12,height = NULL),
                            "Sleep",plotOutput(outputId = "Sleep"))
                ),

                #sixth item conent
                tabItem(tabName="Mood",
                        fluidRow(
                            box(title = "Hi this is the mood page"))
                )

        )
    )
```